# Threshold decomposition in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How do you do reconstruction by threshold decomposition in Matlab? Is there a function for it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more details of the steps in such a procedure? Some of us are not well versed in DSP theory. I did find a link from a book in Google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=P7y2qV0qys8C&lpg=PA115&ots=F3cuKfT7MY&dq=reconstruction%20by%20threshold%20decomposition&pg=PA115#v=onepage&q=reconstruction%20by%20threshold%20decomposition&f=false).

If this is exactly what you want it does not seem difficult to code it up. On the other hand if you want something reliable and optimized for speed maybe on of the DSP toolkit users knows a way.